Correcting a tag
There is a dual-ec-drgb tag.
However, the (in)famous byte generator is actually called DRBG (for Deterministic Random Byte Generator). DRGB makes no sense. Is there a way to fix this, or is this as much set in stone as  'PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT WHITE LENTICULAR BRAKCET' (U+FE18) ?

I fixed this by creating a new tag, and then merging and creating a synonym for both of them, with the correct spelling as master. I also had to copy the wiki for the new tag from the old one myself.
